# Laravel service package that requires another composer package

Tags: laravel, composer-php, package

So i'm trying to create a Laravel service provider.

TLDR; when using a class from my service providers vendors directory it returns class not found,
I think its not being called from my autoloader.

Full Question:

I need to include a few things listed below:

*composer.json*

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
       "erusev/parsedown-extra": "dev-master",
       "symfony/browser-kit": "^4.2@dev"
    }
}
```

When I try to use any of them I get errors such as

> Class 'Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler' not found

My service provider class looks like so:

```
/**
 * Register the application services.
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->make('Namespace\PackageName\DocsController');
}
```

Now the ParsedownExtra is PSR0 so I have gotten past this by just including them

```
/**
 * Register the application services.
 */
public function register()
{
    include_once __DIR__ .'/../vendor/erusev/parsedown/Parsedown.php';
    include_once __DIR__ .'/../vendor/erusev/parsedown-extra/ParsedownExtra.php';

    $this->app->make('Namespace\PackageName\DocsController');
}
```

This I feel is quite messy.

What is the correct way to go about this?

I see there is an extras part in the Laravel docs but this won't work if someone disables package discovery.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/packages#package-discovery

The DocsController essentially publishes a route if the application is in local development which returns my model (class) which uses the Symfony package; I believe the users application is looking for Symfony inside of their own vendors and not loading it from mine.

Comment: Hi Michael! A Composer package and a Laravel service provider are two separate things and not necessarily related. Could you add some details about what your overall goal/intention is? Also, what is `DocsController`?

Comment: Ah thank you for that, I will update it

Comment: Updated the title and also added more information

Comment: Are you trying to develop a package that Laravel devs can install via Composer?

Comment: @AkenRoberts yes that is correct. For some reason its not autoloading my packages requirements correctly.

Comment: Would me setting my namespace inside of a child directory do this? E.g. my vendors folder is outside of the SRC directory so when I 'use' the third party class its not using the correct name spacing?

Comment: I think there's something about your package structure or how it's being loaded that is causing the issue. That's why I am asking questions, because it's not really clear how you've structured your package or how it's being used. Your package's `composer.json` is parsed by the app installing your package, and any requirements are downloaded and auto-loaded there, not in "your" vendor directory (there should only be one vendor directory in an app, usually).

Answer (score 0):

I appreicate your help [Aken Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/580587/aken-roberts)! You were correct, there was something going on with my `composer.json`, I ended up looking at a few other packages and updated mine to be correct.

I will post my composer.json in case anyone else has issues like mine.

```
{
  "name": "namespace/packagename",
  "type": "library",
  "description": "A short description",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "keywords": ["components", "includes", "helpers"],
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket-handle.bitbucket.io/packagename",
  "support": {
    "issues": "https://bitbucket.org/bitbucket-handle/packagename/issues",
    "source": "https://bitbucket.org/bitbucket-handle/packagename"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Author Name",
      "email": "author@email.com",
      "homepage": "https://author-website.com"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "erusev/parsedown-extra": "^0.7.1",
    "symfony/browser-kit": "^4.2@dev"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8.35 || ^5.7"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "NAMESPACE\\PackageName\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": ["@phpunit", "@phpcs"],
    "phpunit": "phpunit --verbose --coverage-clover=coverage.xml",
    "phpcs": "php-cs-fixer fix -v --diff --dry-run",
    "phpstan":
      "phpstan analyse --configuration phpstan.neon --level 3 src tests"
  },
  "extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "providers": ["NAMESPACE\\PackageName\\PackageNameServiceProvider"]
    }
  }
}
```

and below is my project structure:

```
PackageName
|-- CHANGELOG.md
|-- README.md
|-- composer.json
|-- composer.lock
|-- mix-manifest.json
|-- package.json
|-- phpunit.xml.dist
|-- resources
|-- src
|   |-- PackageNameServiceProvider.php
|   |-- DocsController.php
|   |-- Documentation.php
|   |-- assets
|   |-- config
|   |-- docs
|   |-- routes.php
|   `-- views
|-- tests
`-- webpack.mix.js
```

Comment: Great job figuring it out after some direction. Glad I could help! :)